# Best way to save some data and then retrieve it

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a project where I save some data coming from different channels of a Soap Service, for example:

```
String_Value Long_timestamp Double_value String_value String_value Int_value
```

I can have many lines (i.e. 200), with different values, like the one above.

I thought that I could use an `ArrayList`, however data can have a different structure than the one above, so an `ArrayList` maybe isn't a good solution in order to retrieve data from it.
For example above I have, after the first two values that are always fixed, 4 values, but in another channel I may have 3, or 5, values. What I want retrieve data, I must know how many values have a particular line, and I think that `Arraylist` doesn't help me.

What solution could I use?

Comment: "best" in regard to which criteria? Easy to implement? Fast reads/writes? Portable format? Compact storage?

Comment: best regarding the necessity of not having a static structure after the first two elements. For example String_value long_timestamp Singlevalue or String_value long_ts value_one value_two value_three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a need to uniquely identify varying length input, a `HashMap` usually works quite well. For example, you can have a class:

```
public class Record
{
      private HashMap<String, String> values;

      public Record()
      {
           // create your hashmap.
           values = new HashMap<String, String>();
      }

      public String getData(String key)
      {
           return values.get(key);
      }

      public void addData(String key, String value)
      { 
           values.put(key, value);
      }
}
```

With this type of structure, you can save as many different values as you want. What I would do is loop through each value passed from `Soap` and simply add to the `Record`, then keep a list of `Record` objects.

```
Record rec = new Record();
rec.addData("timestamp", timestamp);
rec.addData("Value", value);
rec.addData("Plans for world domination", dominationPlans);
```

Comment: I didn't try yet. I'm studying HashMap Class now and i think it's the right solution

Answer (score 1):

You could build your classes representing the entities and then build a parser ... If it isn't in a standard format (eg JSON, YAML, ecc...) you have no choice to develop your own parser .

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with fields.

```
class ClassName{

int numberOfValues;
String dataString;

...

}
```

Now create an ArrayList of that class like `ArrayList<ClassName>` and for each record fill that class object with numberOfValues and dataString and add in Arraylist.